# Flash object in windows application

Tags: flash, windows-8, app-store

How to add an adobe flash object to Windows 8 JavaScript app store application?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Store JavaScript applications **cannot** use flash- or any other ActiveX control. Only Internet explorer, and only with a specific list of sides, can use flash in the new windows ui.